# Creating a firewall using iptables

Tags: iptables

I need to create a file to filter traffic.

It should work like this:

- Input traffic from 192.168.5.0/24 should be blocked unless it's ICMP or from 192.168.5.200
- Output traffic to 192.168.5.0/24 should be blocked unless it's ICMP or to 192.168.5.200
- The remaining traffic should be allowed.

This is my solution:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p ICMP -s 192.168.5.200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.5.0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p ICMP -d 192.168.5.200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 192.168.5.0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT ACCEPT
```

I'm new to iptables, so I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rules like this:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.5.200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.5.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.5.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.5.200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.5.0/24 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.5.0/24 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the incoming `SSH`. Add this to your script:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

You can also take a look here on this link: [Linux Iptables - Block All Incoming Traffic But Allow SSH](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-4-block-all-incoming-traffic-but-allow-ssh.html)